# Pulling Data from Firebase to a local array, but cannot iterate each item. Length = 0

Tags: arrays, angular, firebase

I have an array and strings defined as such:

```
  Day1;Day2;Day3;Day4;Day5: string;
  BurnData: Array<number> = [];
```

A function as such where I grad the values of their respective days:

```
  grabBurnData(): void{

    this.db.collection('MattDataPull').doc('Board1').get().toPromise().then(r => {
        this.BurnData.push(
        parseInt(r.get('Day1')),
        parseInt(r.get('Day2')),
        parseInt(r.get('Day3')),
        parseInt(r.get('Day4')),
        parseInt(r.get('Day5')));
    });
  }
```

It seems whyen I console.log, the values are within the array but I cannot iterate over them. I get 'undefined'. What is happening here? How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you provide the full code? Better in a stackblitz example

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that your `r.get('Day1')` function will return a `Number`. Try something like this. Change your `BurnData` Array type to `any` just in case to avoid any type casting mistakes.

```
 Day1;Day2;Day3;Day4;Day5: string;
 BurnData: Array<any> = [];

 grabBurnData(): void {
    this.db.collection('MattDataPull').doc('Board1').get().toPromise().then(r => {
          this.BurnData.push(parseInt(r.get('Day1')));
          this.BurnData.push(parseInt(r.get('Day2')));
          this.BurnData.push(parseInt(r.get('Day3')));
          this.BurnData.push(parseInt(r.get('Day4')));
          this.BurnData.push(parseInt(r.get('Day5')));
    });
  }
```